# AWS PHP SDK v3 check if a file exists already in S3 bucket

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-php-sdk

I'm working on a project using PHP and AWS SDK v3 in which I have to check if a file exists already by passing the file name.

Here's what I have tried:

From **HTML template:**

```
<html>
    <form id="form" action="check_existing.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="fName" >
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"><br />
    </form>
</html>
```

From **check_existing.php:**

```
include 'create_client.php';
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){            
    $filename = $_POST['fName'];
    $info = $s3->doesObjectExist($bucketName, $filename);
    print($info);
    if ($info)
    {
        echo 'File exists';
    }
    else
    {
    echo 'File does not exists';
    }
}
```

and here's how I have created `s3` client:

```
$s3 = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
    'region' => $region,
    'version' => 'latest',
    'credentials' => [
        'key'    => $IAM_KEY,
        'secret' => $IAM_SECRET,
    ],
]);
```

> **Problem:**  It always return `File does not exists`

Comment: Looks correct to me. I'd verify that `$s3` is created properly (`print_r($s3);`) and also double check the `$bucketName` and `$filename` values and be sure they are correct.

Comment: `print_r($s3);` giving the response correctly, it means the client is working. I also have double checked the bucket and file names.

Comment: is $region ok? You can check the region of each bucket in the [dashboard](https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/home)

Answer (score 1):

```
$s3 = new S3($s3_accesskey, $s3_secretkey); //create s3 object

$info = $s3->getObjectInfo($s3_bucket, $filename); // $filename can be path of file in bucket
if ($info){
    echo 'File exists';
}else{
    echo 'File does not exists';
}
```

getObjectInfo() returns information as follow

```
Array
(
[date] => 1596690179
[time] => 1596651169
[hash] => 1234c1234341a7f2565c108b23b4aaca
[type] => image/jpeg
[size] => 18968
)
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try this. ref : [enter link description here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_doesObjectExist)

```
$s3 = new AmazonS3();
$bucket = 'your-bucket' . strtolower($s3->key);

$test = $s3->doesObjectExist($bucket, 'testfile.jpg');

// Success or not? (Boolean, not a CFResponse object)
var_dump($test); // it will return boolean
```

Comment: it throws an error: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'AmazonS3' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/s3_php/check_existing.php`

Comment: Hi @nageennayak, just last thing how `var_dump($test)` tells about the object existence? does it return a `boolean`, edit your answer, please! So, I will accept it.

Comment: You can follow the link : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_doesObjectExist